# The year 2018 disappeared from the Photos application on a Macbook Air

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app, data-recovery

For some unknown reason, the rather important year of 2018 disappeared from the Photos application on an Macbook Air with the latest macOS.

The owner insists that nothing was deleted as far as they know, just a gaping hole in the years.

iCloud Photos is not being used.

Where can I look for solutions? Is there a remote possibility to recover the photos using some kind of tool?

If I look in the Photo Library in Finder (Right-click -> Package Contents) I have all folders except 2018.

I am considering a file repair service but wanted to ask if there were other ways before paying for a scan

Comment: Can you open the Photo Library in Finder (Right-click -> Package Contents) and then check whether the 2018 files are still there?

Comment: @nohillside - the folder is missing from there too. I also had a look in other folders to see if it perhaps had been moved by accident

Comment: You can also run ˋfind ~ -type d -name 2018ˋ to check, but right now I think that without a backup these photos might be gone.